# JavaScript Array.includes not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
l = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]

console.log(l.includes([2, 3]))
```

Why does this return false? And how can i check if a list is in a list of list?

Comment: Generic object equality is defined as the objects reside in the same space in memory.  You have two different arrays.  They do not reside in the same memory space.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/201471/2358409

Comment: `toSearch=[1,2];l.some(k=>k.every(p=>toSearch.includes(p)))`

Comment: @gorak That would also match `[1, 2, 9]` or `[2, 1]`

Comment: @Ivar if so then we can match it by taking `stringify` of it.